# How do I apply multiple conditions while filtering in SQL?

Tags: sql, filter, multiple-conditions

I'm very new to SQL and I couldn't find a similar question. I want to select all the OS versions for Android but I only want to select OS versions 11, 15 or higher for IOS.

| **OS Type** | **OS version** |
| --- | --- |
| Android | 8 |
| Android | 11 |
| IOS | 15.1 |
| Other | 15.0.1 |
| IOS | 11 |
| IOS | 14 |
| IOS | 15 |

Comment: What _version_ of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can rephrase your query to:

```
Select the rows where OStype = 'Android' or OStype = 'IOS' and OSversion = 11 or OStype = 'IOS' and OSversion >= 15
```

From there it is straightforward to translate to SQL

```
SELECT OStype, osversion
FROM yourtable
WHERE OStype = 'Android'
   OR OStype = 'IOS' AND OSversion = 11
   OR OStype = 'IOS' and OSversion >= 15
```

Though not necessary, it is a good idea to use parantheses for clarity when mixing AND, OR predicates

```
SELECT OStype, osversion
FROM yourtable
WHERE (OStype = 'Android') 
   OR (OStype = 'IOS' AND OSversion = 11) 
   OR (OStype = 'IOS' and OSversion >= 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for mysql
You can try to use operator >= when you do filter, as you want version which is above version 11

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE
OS_type = 'Android' OR (OS_type = 'IOS' AND OS_version >= 11)
```

You can try on this [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aSn9QK4aMaHLJKEfnUqAgX/0)

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple and it's basic SQL syntax with a lot of examples on Stackoverflow (and the internet as well).

Your case:

```
    SELECT * FROM [your_table] a
    WHERE a.[OS Type] <> 'IOS' 
      OR (a.[OS Type] = 'IOS' 
        AND (a.[OS version] = 11 OR a.[OS version] >= 15))
```

You can find a lot of examples in SQL on:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: `<> 'IOS'` will also include 'Other'

Comment: Also, equals is = in SQL, not ==